# How to persist user data after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have couple of check boxes and input fields. When any of them are checked or any value entered to the input fields, I need to persist these data even after refreshing or URL location change.Can someone help me?

Comment: For browser refresh you need to look at browser `localStorage` supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: I have 5 different forms. One after another. Data to be saved only  when last form is filled. In between this if use refreshes the page, I want data should not lost.

Comment: Here you can find a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895754/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-javascript-variable-that-is-used-in-multiple-html-pag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage of HTML5

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use cookies, they are the most reliable way to save data across browsers, also you can later access it server side. If you don't need expiration or advanced functionality you can use the [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore), otherwise you should use something else.

Although, I would not recommend using this, unless is only for the user experience. If you are relying in this mechanism to give save-like functionality I would strongly recommend you search another approach